# How to create an Eclipse plugin for custom Ant tasks?

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I have written a couple of Ant tasks in Eclipse that may be of use to more people, and am looking for a way to make them easily distributable. Creating an Eclipse plugin that provides these Ant tasks is the first thing that came to mind, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Are there any good tutorials out there on how to create an Eclipse plugin that provides only a couple of Ant targets?

Comment: Just package the ant tasks as jar files and publish them in the Maven Central repository. Users can then download them on demand or use a dependency management tool like ivy. The key point is that one should not need an IDE like Eclipse just to perform a build.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Sorry, perhaps I didn't make myself clear. The Ant tasks that I wrote are *specifically* for projects whose build is performed within Eclipse. So I do think that an Eclipse plugin is the most natural way to go, but I'm happy to be convinced otherwise.